# I have 2 packages with same names but different versions. How to delete any one of them?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

I think the question itself is self-explanatory. But I will just elaborate on it. I already had Sublime Text 3 installed on my Ubuntu, and then I installed the beta version of Sublime Text 4. I downloaded the `.deb` package for Sublime Text 4 and then ran the command `sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-4101_amd64.deb`. After installation, I realized that it might override my current one. I looked up and found there was exactly two software with the same name and icon. Now when I am uninstalling by using the command `sudo apt-get remove sublime-text`, there is only one of them.

Then I ran this command to get the details of the package `apt-cache show sublime-text` and this is the output:

```
Package: sublime-text
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: editors
Installed-Size: 47906
Maintainer: Sublime HQ Pty Ltd <support@sublimetext.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 4101
Depends: libgtk-3-0
Description: Sublime Text is a sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Description-md5: ###
Build-Depends: libgtk-3-0

Package: sublime-text
Priority: optional
Section: editors
Installed-Size: 34033
Maintainer: Sublime HQ Pty Ltd <support@sublimetext.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 3211
Depends: libgtk-3-0
Filename: files/sublime-text_build-3211_amd64.deb
Size: 9835156
MD5sum: ###
SHA1: ###
SHA256: ###
SHA512: ###
Description: Sublime Text is a sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Description-md5: ###
```

So it shows there are two versions. How do I uninstall any one of them?

From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324923/double-package-installed) I tried `apt-cache policy sublime-text` and this is the output:

```
sublime-text:
  Installed: 4101
  Candidate: 4101
  Version table:
 *** 4101 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3211 500
        500 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
```

[image: Double Sublime Text Screenshot]

Output for `snap list | grep -i sublime`:

```
sublime-text       3211                        97     latest/stable    snapcrafters  classic
```

**[Solved]**

One of the Sublime Text was installed using `apt` and the other with `snap`. So I uninstalled the `snap` one with the command `sudo snap remove sublime-text`

Comment: You uninstall using the counterpart of installing. you apt purge an apt install, you "rm"  a tar ball install, you snap delete a snap install. You can in theory only install ONE version using `apt install sublime-text`. The other needs to have had a different name or different installation method. Otherwise it would by design replace the old one.

Comment: Yes i used a `.deb` package and installed using `sudo dpkg -i sublime-text...deb`

Comment: @N0rbert I have added the output from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324923/double-package-installed

Comment: So you have installed only one version (4101) of the package.

Comment: @N0rbert But the problem is that, there are still two softwares with the name Sublime Text with the same icon too, that must mean there is another package installed too right? How do I delete that? I have added the screenshot too

Comment: I think it worked, I uninstalled it and installed it again and it works now. But I still have the two icon problem. It is not two different softwares now, rather two icons opening the same sublime text. Any solution around that?

Comment: Then check the output of `snap list | grep -i sublime` and `flatpak list | grep -i sublime` .

Comment: I have added the output for the first one. But I don't get any output for `flatpak list | grep -i sublime`

Comment: Ok thanks it worked. I removed it using `sudo snap remove sublime-text`